# How do I center two divs that are side by side?

Tags: html, css

I am wanting to center the Div #Content & #Sidebar, this is my code, can someone explain how I would do this given the Divs are side by side?

I have updated my existing post to provide more information - Thanks!

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <div class="header">Title of Website</div>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
            <div class="menu"><img src="images/menusample.png" alt="sample of js menu"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">Main content</div>

        <div id="sidebar">Sidebar/Widget</div>

        <div id="footer">Footer</div>

    </div>
</body>
```

**style.css:**

```
    body {
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-image:url('images/nifla-bg.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;

}

#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#header {
    width:100%;
    height: 90px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image:url('images/header-bg.png');
}

#menu {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#F4F4F4;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}


#content {
    width:700px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;

}

#sidebar {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    background-color:gray;

}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    width:100%;
    height:90px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image:url('images/footer-bg.png');
}

.header {
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:15px;
}

.curly-font {
    font-family:'Pacifico', Verdana;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.menu {
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to center the `div` that has a width of 1000px, than you can use `margin:0 auto;`

**Example:**

```
 <div id="container">   
    <div id="content">Main content</div>
    <div id="sidebar">Sidebar/Widget</div>
 </div>
```

**css:**

```
#container {width:1000px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/khh7qses/)**

Answer (score 2):

Wrap them in another div, position it relatively and add `margin: 0 auto;`. Easy does it ;)

(widths in the snippet below are just to visualize the effect)

```css
#content {
  width:70px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  background-color:blue;

}

#sidebar {
  width:30px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  background-color:grey;

}
#wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

HTML

```
    <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="content">Main content</div>

    <div id="sidebar">Sidebar/Widget</div>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #wrapper {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #content {
        width:700px;
        height:auto;
        float:left;
        background-color:blue;

    }

    #sidebar {
        width:300px;
        height:auto;
        float:left;
        background-color:gray;

    }
```